# sort by boolean value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have array of following class

```
export class Tests {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  createdAt: any;
  succress: boolean;

  constructor(id: number, name: string, createdAt: any, success: boolean) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
    this.succress = success;
  }
}
```

And I want to sort it by value of success (false on top and true on bottom). How can I do that?

I've tried

```
this.tests.sort((a,b)=> b.succress - a.succress);
```

But is not doing anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort by boolean value as follows:

```
this.tests.sort((a, b) => {
   if (a.succress === b.succress) {
      return 0;
   }

   if (a.succress) {
      return -1;
   }

   if (b.succress) {
      return 1;
   }
});
```

Comment: Nitpicking here but would it not be more correct to first check if `a === b` return 0 if `a === true` return -1 then return 1. Now when a and b are the same it would return 1 or -1 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
[false,true,false,true]
.sort(
  (a,b)=>
    (a===b)?0
    :(a===true)?1:-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using **[lodash sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy)** function

```
_.sortBy(this.users,['succress'])
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/YYVnj2KXkDbn2MMeKvaQ?p=preview)**